# How to invoke method on Enum class using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Need to call the method on the enum class, which i dont have direct build dependency. I want to call the method on enum class using the reflection using java.

I have tried using the Field as well, but no luck

```
class myClass
{
  public void validateObjectType(Object obj)
  {
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName("package1.myEnum");
    Class [] parameterTypes = {Object.class};
    Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("getMyEnum", parameterTypes );
    String enumType = (String)method.invoke(null, new Object[]{obj1}); 

    Field enumTypeField = cls.getField(enumType );

   // -- invoke method getLocalName() on the object of the enum class.??
   Class [] parameters = {String.class};
            Method method1= cls.getDeclaredMethod("getLocalName", parameters);

String localizedName = (String) method1.invoke(enumTypeField , new Object[] {enumType});

  }

}
```

However i am getting error at

```
method1.invoke(enumTypeField , new Object[] {}) //
```

Error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

Package 1:

```
class enum myEnum
{

  A, 
  B;

 public static myEnum getMyEnum(Object a)
 {
   // business logic.
   // -- based on the type of object decide MyEnum
   if (null != object) return B;
   else  return A ;
 }

 public String getLocalName(String value)
 {
   if (value.equal(A.toString) return "my A";
   else if(value.equal(B.toString) return "my B";   
 }

}
```

Package 2:

// -- Here i dont have build dependency on package 1.
// --- dont want to add, as it will lead to cyclic dependency

```
class myClass
{

  public void validateObjectType(Object obj)
  {
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName("package1.myEnum");
    Class [] parameterTypes = {Object.class};
    Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("getMyEnum", parameterTypes );
    ?? = (??)method.invoke(null, new Object[] {obj1}); // will get the Enum but dont have acces

   // -- invoke method getLocalName() on the object of the enum class.??
  }

}
```

Comment: Why does `getLocalName` take a `String` parameter? Shouldn't return the local name of `this`?

Comment: Its just a psudo code that i have added. in production code, we just get it from the resource file based on the ID of enum class

Comment: So does `getLocalName` take a parameter or not in production?

Comment: This is pseudo code. Production code is different. In production code this method does not take argument.

Comment: So this isn't the real code. So your question is presently futile.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is trying to convert the result of `getMyEnum` into a `String`. `getMyEnum` returns a `myEnum`, so you should not convert it to a `String`. Just leave it as an `Object`:

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("package1.myEnum");
Class [] parameterTypes = {Object.class};
Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("getMyEnum", parameterTypes);
Object enumValue = method.invoke(null, obj);
```

And since you said `getLocalName` doesn't actually accept any parameters, you can just get the method and call it like this:

```
Method method1= cls.getDeclaredMethod("getLocalName");

String localizedName = (String) method1.invoke(enumValue); // <-- using enumValue here!
System.out.println(localizedName);
```

You don't need the `enumTypeField` variable because `enumValue` is already the enum value we are going to call `getLocalName` on.

Answer (score 0):

The `Method.invoke` call requires an object of the type that the method is from as the first parameter. You are passing a `Field` instead (in the second call).

If you want to get a particular enum by its name you can use the `valueOf` method and pass that in.

Comment: I can not import the myEnum class from the package 1. So i am not sure on which object i should call valueOf